# Are PWAs published to Play Store installable without any browsers installed on device?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I found that Google Play Store allows publishing progressive web apps (PWA) as an apk. Bit confused about a few things,

1. When downloading a PWA from play store is it required to have some particular version of chrome or other browsers installed on device?
2. Will the cookies, local storage, session storage still work as expected on PWAs?
3. Does permissions such as location, file storage required by the PWA need to be given to the particular PWA or to the browser that is running it?

Can't seem to find much resources talking about the capabilities/limitations of PWAs installed from Google Play Store. Any relevant links on the topic would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Yes, it is

**Long answer:**

According to a reliable source ([web.dev](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/progressive-web-apps/#web)):

> People tend to think of Progressive Web Apps as an app that the user can install from a browser instead of an app store. However, a PWA can be listed in many app stores today as an optional distribution channel, including Google Play Store (for Android and ChromeOS), Microsoft Store (for Windows 10 and 11), and Apple AppStore (for iOS, iPadOS, and macOS). For these cases, you must follow all store rules and requirements, but you will still get some of the advantages of a PWA.

Now regarding how to publish a PWA to a store, let's say Play Store, as you requested, there is a tool that you need called **Bubblewrap**.

If you want to know how to use this tool, here is a detailed step-by-step guide from Google: https://developers.google.com/codelabs/pwa-in-play#0

Comment: thanks! I went through the codelab and it says Bubblewrap wraps PWAs into an Android App Bundle as a Trusted Web Activity. And in here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/ it says chrome browser version 72 is required for Trusted Web Activity. Then how will a PWA (bundled as a Trusted Web Activity) run without any browsers installed? I'm still pretty confused. Is there a way I can test this by publishing a dummy web app converted to a PWA without needing to pay 25 dollars for a google developers account?

Comment: So I did some more experiments generating apks using Bubblewrap. Turns out you need a browser installed on device to run PWAs published to playstore with apk/aab built using bubblewrap. The default browser is used for launching the app if you don't have any then there is a prompt to permit a browser to launch the app. Bubblewrap uses Trusted Web Activity feature and simply creates an Android project with a LaucherActivity that opens the link which is viewed in a similar way we view links opened from within an app. Not a very nice way to publish apps to play store imo.